# MarkLogic returns incorrect results for a sparql query

Tags: sparql, marklogic

MarkLogic returns incorrect results when a sparql query is executed in its query console.

*Dummy data:*

Scenario: There's a Folder object and it has child objects of type File. All objects have label. Each Folder/File has a relation called `WritePermission` which tells the Group that has permission to modify it.

```
prefix ex: <http://example.com/ns#>
prefix rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
prefix rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>

insert data {
  ex:ID0 rdfs:label "Root" .
  ex:ID0 rdf:type ex:Folder .
  ex:ID0 ex:WritePermission ex:GROUP1 . 
  ex:ID1 rdfs:label "File1" .
  ex:ID1 rdf:type ex:File .
  ex:ID1 ex:Parent ex:ID0 .
  ex:ID1 ex:WritePermission ex:GROUP2 . 
  ex:ID2 rdfs:label "File2" .
  ex:ID2 rdf:type ex:File .
  ex:ID2 ex:Parent ex:ID0 .
  ex:ID2 ex:WritePermission ex:GROUP2 . 
  ex:ID3 rdfs:label "File3" .
  ex:ID3 rdf:type ex:File .
  ex:ID3 ex:Parent ex:ID0 .
  ex:ID3 ex:WritePermission ex:GROUP2 .
  ex:GROUP1 rdf:type ex:Group .
  ex:GROUP1 rdfs:label "Admin" .
  ex:GROUP1 ex:Member ex:USER1 .
  ex:GROUP2 rdf:type ex:Group .
  ex:GROUP2 rdfs:label "Users" .
  ex:GROUP2 ex:Member ex:USER2 .
  ex:USER1 rdf:type ex:User .
  ex:USER1 rdfs:label "User1" .
  ex:USER2 rdf:type ex:User .
  ex:USER2 rdfs:label "User2" .
}
```

---

*Query:*

Following query is expected to tell whether a given name already exists under given Parent ("Root"). Second exists clause checks whether an object belongs to a group which has write permission to the given Parent ID "Root".

```
prefix ex: <http://example.com/ns#>
prefix rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>

select ?nameConflict ?hasWritePermissionToParent
where { 
  bind(ex:ID0 as ?parent)
  bind("""ZZZ""" as ?nameToCheck)
  bind(ex:USER2 as ?userId)

  bind(exists { ?parent ^ex:Parent/rdfs:label ?nameToCheck } as ?nameConflict)
  bind(exists { ?userId ^ex:Member+/^ex:WritePermission ?parent } as ?hasWritePermissionToParent)
}
```

---

*Expected:* Both `?nameConflict` and `?hasWritePermissionToParent` should return `false`

*Actual:* Both return `true`

---

*MarkLogic version:* 11.0.2

This is also seen in MarkLogic v10

---

Is there anything wrong with the query ? Is any DB setting affecting the results ?

---

#### Update

MarkLogic confirms this is a bug. However the workaround `select *` too doesn't work and is highly inconsistent.

Scenario is changed a little bit, three more triples describing read permission are added:

*Data:*

```
prefix ex: <http://example.com/ns#>
prefix rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
prefix rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>

insert data {
  ex:ID0 rdfs:label "Root" .
  ex:ID0 rdf:type ex:Folder .
  ex:ID0 ex:ReadPermission ex:GROUP1 .
  ex:ID0 ex:WritePermission ex:GROUP1 . 
  ex:ID1 rdfs:label "File1" .
  ex:ID1 rdf:type ex:File .
  ex:ID1 ex:Parent ex:ID0 .
  ex:ID1 ex:ReadPermission ex:GROUP2 .
  ex:ID1 ex:WritePermission ex:GROUP2 . 
  ex:ID2 rdfs:label "File2" .
  ex:ID2 rdf:type ex:File .
  ex:ID2 ex:Parent ex:ID0 .
  ex:ID2 ex:ReadPermission ex:GROUP2 .
  ex:ID2 ex:WritePermission ex:GROUP2 . 
  ex:ID3 rdfs:label "File3" .
  ex:ID3 rdf:type ex:File .
  ex:ID3 ex:Parent ex:ID0 .
  ex:ID3 ex:ReadPermission ex:GROUP2 .
  ex:ID3 ex:WritePermission ex:GROUP2 .
  ex:GROUP1 rdf:type ex:Group .
  ex:GROUP1 rdfs:label "Admin" .
  ex:GROUP1 ex:Member ex:USER1 .
  ex:GROUP2 rdf:type ex:Group .
  ex:GROUP2 rdfs:label "Users" .
  ex:GROUP2 ex:Member ex:USER2 .
  ex:USER1 rdf:type ex:User .
  ex:USER1 rdfs:label "User1" .
  ex:USER2 rdf:type ex:User .
  ex:USER2 rdfs:label "User2" .
}
```

*Query:*

```
prefix ex: <http://example.com/ns#>
prefix rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>

select *
where { 
  bind(ex:ID0 as ?id)

  ex:USER1 ^ex:Member+ ?groups .

  bind(exists{?id ex:ReadPermission ?groups} as ?hasReadPermission)
  bind(exists{?id ex:Source/ex:ReadPermission ?groups ; ex:Destination/ex:ReadPermission ?groups .} as ?linkHasReadPermission)
}
```

*Expected results:*

| ?id | User | Expected ?hasReadPermission |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ID0 | ex:USER1 | true |
| ID0 | ex:USER2 | false |
| ID1/ID2/ID3 | ex:USER1 | false |
| ID1/ID2/ID3 | ex:USER2 | true |

For the first row of values, at first it looks like it returns expected results. However when you try **all** combinations presented in the table above at some point you'll get an incorrect result, hence the inconsistency.

Comment: In RDFox I'm getting `false` `false` as you're expecting.

Comment: I'm not familiar with MarkLogic, but this would suggest that it's something to do with its settings. Maybe you could try to change the `BIND(EXISTS{...})` statements to debug what's going on.
You could also get rid of the property paths for debugging purposes.

Comment: Try this query and see if the results are any different:
`PREFIX ex: <http://example.com/ns#>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>

SELECT ?nameConflict ?hasWritePermissionToParent
WHERE {

  BIND (EXISTS {?child rdfs:label "ZZZ" ;
        ex:hasParent ex:ID0} AS ?nameConflict)
  BIND (EXISTS { ex:ID0 ex:WritePermission ?permission .
                ?permission ex:Member+ ex:USER2 } AS ?hasWritePermissionToParent)

}`

Comment: @valerio Directly assigning values in the exists clause returns correct results (even with property paths). This is most likely a bug in MarkLogic. Thanks for your comments.

Answer (score 2):

Interestingly, replacing `select ?nameConflict ?hasWritePermissionToParent` by `select *` returns the right answer.  Maybe you can use that as a workaround.

But this looks like a bug to me.  You should report it.  If you need help for that, I can help you, look at my profile for other ways to contact me directly.

Comment: A support ticket is created with MarkLogic

Comment: MarkLogic confirms this is a bug in their implementation. And `select *` does not work always, I have added another example where it fails in the original question.